# SwiftUI transmit drag focus to outer view (ScrollView inside dragable)

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

**What I want**

I have a "ScrollView" in a custom sheet that I can drag down to close. Of course, the `ScrollView` is above the drag area, so when I drag over the `ScrollView` it scrolls down or up. I want to disable the ScrollView when I am at the top of the `ScrollView` and scroll up so that the sheet is dragged and starts to close. This is similar to the behaviour of the Shazam sheet.

**The Problem**

If the `ScrollView` is deactivated, the current drag action is not applied to the sheet, but does nothing. Only when dragging again (on the now deactivated `ScrollView`) the sheet is focused on the dragging. **So is there a way to transfer the focus of the drag action from the `ScrollView` to the outer sheet view without starting a new one?**

**Showcase**

I created a simplified version of the problem for better understanding.

We have a container (`inner`) that is draggable along the y-axis. On drag release, we let it jump back to offset 0.

```swift
@State var offsetY: CGFloat = .zero

    var body: some View {
        Inner(outerOffset: $offsetY)
            .offset(y: offsetY)
            .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                offsetY = value.translation.height
            }.onEnded { _ in
                offsetY = 0
            }
            )
    }
```

Inside the container we have our own ScrollView ([`ScrollViewOffset`](https://github.com/FiveStarsBlog/CodeSamples/blob/main/ScrollView-Offset/ScrollViewOffset.swift)) which takes a callback with the current scroll offset. If the offset is positive (i.e. if we are scrolling upwards, even if we are at the top of the content), we want to disable the scroll and let the outer container drag along the y-axis instead of the `ScrollView`. To activate the `ScrollView` we listen for the `outerOffset` (the drag value) and activate the `ScrollView` when the offset is `0` again (this happens when releasing the drag as described before).

```swift
struct Inner: View {
    @Binding var outerOffset: CGFloat
    @State var disableScroll = false

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollViewOffset {
                ForEach(0 ... 10, id: \.self) { e in
                    Text(String(e))
                        .id(e)
                        .padding()
                    Divider()
                }
            } onOffsetChange: { offset in
                if offset > 0 {
                    disableScroll = true
                }
            }
            .background(.red)
            .padding()
            .frame(width: nil, height: 400)
            .onChange(of: outerOffset) { _ in
                if outerOffset == 0 {
                    proxy.scrollTo(0)
                    disableScroll = false
                }
            }
            .disabled(disableScroll)
        }
    }
}
```

When we run this, it is easy to see the problem I mentioned before. The `ScrollView` is getting disabled as it should, but the container is not focused on the drag. Only after starting a new drag, the container is focused.

[image: Demo showcase]

**My actual case**

Last but not least the shazam equivalent (left) and my project (right).

[image: Shazam Demo]
[image: Prop Demo]

Comment: Any progress on a solution? I'm seeing the same problem when using a ScrollViewOffset inside of another ScrollViewOffset. Grateful for any additional insights you found since your original question

Comment: @Chris I made a custom version of this sheet https://github.com/lucaszischka/BottomSheet that uses a UIScrollView wrapper that delegates the drag movement on the sheet to the offset inside the scrollView. It was quite hard to make it work the way I wanted....

Comment: Thanks. It does look fairly complicated. I'm just hoping to hand off control between an inner and outer scrollview: When swiping down and inner scrollview offset reaches zero, automatically continue scrolling the outer scrollview. When swiping up and outer scrollview offset reaches a certain value, relinquish scrolling to inner scrollview. So seeking a way to transfer the focus of the scroll action from the inner ScrollView to the outer ScrollView without starting a new scroll gesture. Structure: Outer ScrollView contains a TabView and each page of TabView is a an Inner ScrollView.

Comment: If you find a way to do this, please let me know! Could not find such a mechanism...